# MongoDB Compass Freezes When Adding ca.crt Certificate During New Connection Setup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

After downloading (from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass)) and installation of MongoDB Compass (1.37.0), when I add the ca.crt certificate in the new connection page, the application freezes.

I tried to re-install the app, but the problem is still there and I cannot proceed.

Answer (score -1):

1. Verify Certificate Format: Ensure that the ca.crt certificate file
   is in the correct format and not corrupted. Double-check that you
   have the correct certificate file and it's not mistakenly named with
   a different extension. If possible, try opening the certificate file
   using a text editor to confirm its contents.
2. Use the Latest Version: Check if there is an updated version of
   MongoDB Compass available. It's possible that the freezing issue
   you're facing is a known bug that has been fixed in a newer release.
   Upgrading to the latest version might resolve the problem.
3. Clear Application Data: Try clearing the application data of MongoDB
   Compass to reset any cached settings that might be causing
   conflicts. You can typically find an option to clear application
   data in the settings or preferences section of the application.
   Clearing the data will reset the application to its default state,
   so make sure to back up any necessary configurations or connections
   beforehand.
4. Run as Administrator: Launch MongoDB Compass with administrative
   privileges. Right-click on the application icon and choose "Run as
   Administrator" to ensure it has the necessary permissions to perform
   the required operations. This can sometimes resolve issues related
   to accessing and loading certificate files.
5. Disable Antivirus/Firewall: Temporarily disable any antivirus or
   firewall software running on your system. These security tools can
   sometimes interfere with the proper functioning of MongoDB Compass,
   including the handling of certificate files. Disabling them
   temporarily can help identify if they are the cause of the freezing
   issue.
6. Reinstall MongoDB Compass: If none of the above steps resolve the
   freezing problem, try completely uninstalling MongoDB Compass and
   then reinstalling it from scratch. This will ensure that any
   corrupted or misconfigured files are removed, and you'll have a
   fresh installation to work with.

If the freezing issue persists after trying these steps, it's recommended to reach out to the MongoDB support team or consult the MongoDB Compass documentation for further assistance. They can provide specific guidance based on your operating system, version of MongoDB Compass, and the nature of the problem you're facing.